# .htaccess to remove .php extension breaks xml file

Tags: php, xml, .htaccess, sitemap, google-search-console

I'm using the following htaccess to remove the `.php` or `.html` extension from the url:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I have a file called `sitemap.xml` for the website's sitemap. When I try to submit the sitemap to Google through `Google Webmaster Tools`, I think its treating the `sitemap.xml` file as a `php` file and throws the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'version' (T_STRING) in /home/eliteche/public_html/sitemap.xml on line 1
```

Can anyone please help me so solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Which part of the error message puzzles you most?

Comment: @hakre Error says that there is something wrong in version of my xml file but I guess that is correct. So don't know what is causing issue.

Comment: The XML is correct, that's most likely. But: what if the XML is read as PHP? Then you'll see PHP giving you that error message ... . This is the case here. ou have to disable PHP short-open tags ("`<?`") for that file.

Comment: @hakre I tried `<?php echo <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> ?>` as suggested somewhere in stackoverflow. But it didn't work.

Comment: Well the other thing you tried didn't work either. But what we can say from the error message is that the XML is interpreted as PHP. Stop doing that and it will work. And if you tried things, outline them as well and give the reference to the existing material. This helps to distinguish your question from existing ones.

Comment: @hakre Can you tell me how should I do that? What would have you done in such case?

Comment: Which error do you get when you try the workaround/suggestion?

Comment: @hakre In that prints everything like a php file

Comment: so no error? but it does not execute the PHP code then?

Comment: And have you tried switching short open tags off?

Comment: No, I didn't switch off the short tags. But using `echo` works. Though it does not print things like xml file, the sitemap did get submitted. Thanks!